# Backup a directory of another app on button press

Tags: android

I would like to backup a directory of another app in android and store that directory in the device in a separate folder.

And then, later on, I need a way to restore that directory back into the apps folder I backed it up from (If that makes sense).

Comment: That's nice. What's your question about what you have attempted? You may want to know that app's private data cannot be accessed outside of that app, so your task may prove difficult.

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry the full question didn't save: The app I want to backup from is called Kodi. I need a way to backup an xml file from a directory and save it to the device, I know that this app isn't protected so I can do it. Any ideas?

Comment: You may [edit] your question to include additional details

Comment: Although, it may get flagged as a duplicate because regardless of what app you are using reading & writing from internal & external storage has already been asked and answered